# Error con apache en xampp(tampoco me funciona en wampp) Apache shutdown unexpectely

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache, xampp, wamp

**Xampp** cuando trato de iniciar **apache**, me da el tipico error **shutdown unexpectedly**[image: Error Xampp]
y siguiendo videos de yt y otros blogs hice aquello de cambiar los puertos y etc, la cosa es que no me funciono, decidi desinstalar xampp y me cerciore de eliminar todo rastro y lo reinstale normal como siempre, el problema continuo... probe usar **wampp** y el apache tampoco me funcionaba.. decidi mirar a los servicios(**services.msc**) y encontre apache que no estaba iniciado y trate de iniciarlo manualmente y me da este error [image: Error en servicios de windows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de que el puerto 80 que usa apache esta siendo ocupado por otro servicio. Pruebe a detener todos los servicios uno por uno en el administrador y a iniciar el apache uno de esos servicios está ocupando el puerto 80. Obviamente vuelva a inciar los servicios que estaban activos una vez los vaya probando.

Comment: No, eso tambien lo probe, ya encontre la solucion... habia formateado windows totalmente y no tenia microsft c++ redistributable.

Comment: Perfecto tema cerrado. Otra opción muy común suele ser servicios que utilizan ese puerto como te dije. Perfecto